# What are the little pieces of wood that come with pre-made canvas for?

Tags: painting, canvas

I buy pre-made canvases, and they always come with a little packet of wooden things:

[image: Canvas wooden things]

What are they for? How should I use them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are called "[canvas keys](http://painting.about.com/od/paintingforbeginners/a/canvaskeys.htm)".

The are shimmed into the corners of the canvas to maintain the tautness of the canvas.  This generally happens only on machine-assembled frames, or on mass-produced frames that have low-quality inspection standards (for cost).

Comment: How exactly do you do that? Which way round do they go into the slots? How hard should you push them in?

Comment: @TomMedley if you follow the link, you will find how to use them. You push them as hard as it is suitable for you.

Comment: @TomMedley I'd actually recommend making that a new question. "How to use canvas keys." It'd get my upvote, and generate some specific answers.

Comment: They are also used on good quality canvas as even the best canvas can stretch over time.